# 3D Touch on responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, 3dtouch

I want to implement 3D Touch on my hybrid application. I can get it working using `self.webView.allowsLinkPreview = true;`

But now the issue is when I click on Help link it needs to current session to open the help content. Is it possible to pass any parameters to webview for 3D Touch to open the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you can use **peek and pop** feature in 3D Touch. For complete guide for peek and pop feature refer following links.

1. https://the-nerd.be/2015/10/06/3d-touch-peek-and-pop-tutorial/
2. http://krakendev.io/peek-pop/

Just keep one webView in target View Controller and keep one property called "link" in that view controller class. While use do 3D Touch update your link property value in

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

//create the instance of the target view controller and assign the link you want to open to "link" property

}
```

Then open that link using

```
myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: link!))
```